# Python partial string match using list comprehension

Tags: python, string, list-comprehension

I am trying to use list comprehensions to edit a list based on partial string match. I need to replace all elements in `group` column of df which contains `L` with `Left`

```
['Left' if x.str.contains('L') else x for x in df['group']]
```

It wont let me apply str.contains or `'L' in x`. For latter it says `argument of type 'float' is not iterable`

Any suggestion would be welcome.

**EDIT: ADDING DATA**

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['group']=[u'L1', u'L2', u'L3', u'R1', u'R2', u'R3']
```

Comment: How about some sample data for us to work with? Right now, the only thing that we could tell you is that `x` is probably not what you think it is.

Comment: What type is `x`? A float, a string, or an object with a property named `str`?

Comment: @tobias_k and Jason S, yes I should have provided the data but I just thought someone might figure out just by looking at it and Craig's answer works perfectly.

Comment: My guess is that your data contains mixed types, which in itself is probably bad design and should be reconsidered. In this case, using `'L' in str(x)` could work, but it could also go horribly wrong for other data sets. I recommend something like `'Left' if (isinstance(x, WhatEverTypeXShouldBe) and 'L' x.str) else x`, but without actual data that's just a guess.

Comment: @tobias_k, thanks for the warning. Right now I do not have control on my data source so cannot do much about it. However, I will try to work with your solution as it sounds more fool proof but yes my data does contain mixed type!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast x to a string like below

```
['Left' if 'L' in str(x) else x for x in df['group']]
```

But, if x is being interpreted as a float it sounds like an issue with the data source, unless it is viable for df['group'] to contain both strings and floats?

EDIT:

If both floats and strings are in your data I'd suggest only looking for 'L' in the strings:

```
['Left' if isinstance(x, unicode) and u'L' in x else x for x in df['group']]
```

Comment: This does not "cast" x to string, but creates a string representation of x, which is something entirely different. This _could_ work, but just as likely it could not.

Comment: This was precisely the problem and worked perfectly. I think I was wrong in saying it is treating it as float.

Comment: Your second approach is more like it (see my comment under the question), but I don't think that those elements are actually strings, but rather some other class. Otherwise OP's code with `x.str` should have produced an AttributeError.

Comment: Yeah, I agree about the AttributeError. I didn't consider that case.

Comment: I have pasted the code which will generate the data. It is basically unicode strings. First solution provided by craig works but the updated one based on @tobias_k adivse does not seem to work. I will still like to understand what is the right way of going about it.

Comment: If you know the data you want to check is unicode, you can change the isinstance check to unicode. I've updated my answer to account for the expected data being unicode.